# Workbook.AcceptLabelsInFormulas Property removed from Office 2007 onwards. Any work around?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

We use excel export for reporting functionality. Charts are also prepared using the data which is available.

Now, since Excel 2003 has Workbook.AcceptLabelsInFormulas Property, the code runs fine. But with the removal of this property from Excel 2007 onward, whenever the code is run, it throws OLE object error.

I want to know whether any work around is available OR the code has to be changed with the cell number and range? Any hint is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Accept Labels in Formulas property was deprecated as per this [MSDN article](http://blogs.office.com/2006/08/24/deprecated-features-for-excel-2007/).

The workaround appears to be to used named ranges to refer to the specific label cells.  So if in cell A1, you had the label `ID`, you could just create the Named Range, `ID` (which can be either Workbook or Worksheet specific).  There are then a variety of ways to refer to the adjacent cells, one way is to use a numerical index and offset from that Named Range, like

```
Range("ID").Offset(0,i)
```

Comment: Thanks Lance. I'll explore this option.

Comment: Thanks Naveen & Richard!